PyCharm - pip install vs run time python directories
PyCharm 2021.2.4 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-212.5712.39, built on December 20, 2021
(I will try new version of PyCharm, I thought I just installed a new version a few months ago).
30 minutes ago, I saw a screen in PyCharm where I changed where PIP should install to, I set it to c:\python312...
But then, I could not create an virtual environment for Python 3.12, due to distutils missing; so a few tries to fix that didn't work.
So now I want to reset PIP to install in c:\python311..., but I can't find that screen again.  I thought it was in settings or "run configurations", but don't see it now.
I think this is what I'm looking for, but the instructions are not working:

(From: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pipenv.html#pipenv-existing-project)
Ok, I now see that only appears when you do "Add New environment".  Can I not find the same screen for the existing environment?
I tried to add a new environment, but I have no idea what to put for "Pipenv executable".  I can go search disk for it, but for now, I'm stuck there:

5 minutes later - I tried "c:\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe".
And got this error:


I upgraded to the most recent version, and I was able to setup Python 3.12.
(I had no idea I was that far behind, because I thought I had upgraded just a few weeks or months ago.)
